# Find item in listview using textbox_changed event VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

my plan is to search data or item in listview using textbox_changed event and eliminate other item with no contain string on textbox.. but when i insert any text in textbox all item in listview is dissapeard or missing and if i clear textbox all item still missing or no item in listview.. i have search on google to, and using various code on google, but still my problem is same.

this is how i insert data into listview :

```
Private Sub BtnOpenPCostumer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpenPCostumer.Click
    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim command As OleDbCommand
    Dim data_reader As OleDbDataReader
    connection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & App_Path & "\Costumer\PCostumer\PCostumer.accdb")
    connection.Open()
    command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TblPCostumer", connection)
    data_reader = command.ExecuteReader
    If data_reader.HasRows Then
        While data_reader.Read

            Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()
            newitem.Text = data_reader.GetValue(0)
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(1))
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(2))
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(3))
            newitem.SubItems.Add(data_reader.GetValue(4))
            ListView1.Items.Add(newitem)
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

and this is how i search data in listview.

```
  Private Sub TxtFindCostumer_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TxtFindCostumer.TextChanged
    Dim TrueList As New List(Of ListViewItem)
    ListView1.BeginUpdate()
    If TxtFindCostumer.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For Each item In TrueList
            ListView1.Items.Add(item)
        Next
    Else
        ListView1.Items.Clear()
        For Each item In TrueList
            If item.Text.Contains(TxtFindCostumer.Text) Then
                ListView1.Items.Add(item)
            End If
        Next
    End If
    ListView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

i have found many solution using this code and other people success with this code but not for me.. maybe i miss something here... sorry for my bad english.. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
Dim TrueList As New List(Of ListViewItem)
```

creates an EMPTY list of ListViewItem everytime the TextChanged event is fired. The List is empty and so, after calling

```
ListView1.Items.Clear()
```

you are unable to set the content of the listview to something useful.

If the contents of your table is not very big you could move the declaration of the TrueList variable at the form level and fill it when you fill the ListView in the button click event

```
' At the form level
Dim TrueList As New List(Of ListViewItem) 


.....

Private Sub BtnOpenPCostumer_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpenPCostumer.Click

    ....

    data_reader = command.ExecuteReader
    If data_reader.HasRows Then
        While data_reader.Read
            Dim newitem As New ListViewItem()
            .....
            ' Add the ListViewItem to the ListView.Items collection
            ListView1.Items.Add(newitem)
            ' Add the same ListViewItem to the List(Of ListViewItem) 
            ' used in the TextChanged event to filter the ListView content
            TrueList.Add(newItem)
        End While
    End If
End Sub
```

Of course remove the declaration and initialization of TrueList inside the TextChanged event

Comment: Okay sir, First i get error point to TxtFindCostumer_TextChanged Else "ListView1.Items.Add(item)" when i insert any text into textbox.. so i try to change "Dim Truelist" into "Private Truelist".. And now is working sir thank you.

Comment: i almost forgot sir.. this code is working now.. but it just can find on first collumn.. how can i to search from second collumn or third collumn..

Comment: That's a different problem then. I suggest to post a new question with the relevant info.